# Change color of the bar based on column on Superset

Tags: apache-superset

its been a month since I started using Apache Superset. I have a graph that gives the accuracy of an event occuring on a given hour shown below.
[image: Example Graph]

The event occuring is a column named 'prediction' which is either 'Left' or 'Right'. Is there a way to colorize the bars according to the value in 'prediction' column. If the prediction is Left then red colored bar and green colored bar when Right etc. I have checked metadata but I am not sure how I can edit it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If there is only 1 event for every hour, then you can add 'prediction' column in breakdown section of bar chart and use Stacked bar view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using the 'prediction' column in breakdown function few days ago. Thank you Kamal for providing an answer as well!